# yii2 updating tabular set of data is not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html#collecting-tabular-input

i worked based on the above link but my data is not updating to the database

my table structure is

**setting**

**id , name, value**

My controller  SettingsController.php

```
 <?php

 namespace backend\controllers;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\Model;
 use yii\web\Controller;
 use backend\models\Setting;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{


public function actionIndex()
{
    $settings = Setting::find()->indexBy('id')->all();

    if (Model::loadMultiple($settings, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($settings)) {
        foreach ($settings as $setting) {
            $setting->save(false);
        }
        return $this->redirect('update');
    }

    return $this->render('update', ['settings' => $settings]);
  }
}
```

my model is Setting.php

```
<?php
namespace backend\models;
use Yii;
class Setting extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

  public static function tableName()
  {
     return 'setting';
  }

}
```

view is under settings -- update.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
 foreach ($settings as $index => $setting) {
      echo $form->field($setting, "[$index]value")->label($setting->name);
 }
 ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php
ActiveForm::end();
```

my problem is updated data is not saving.but i'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any rules or safe attribute in your `Setting` Model then  the values of this model are not available..

try adding the list of save attribute in rule for your model..

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
       [['field1', 'field2',,,,'fieldn'], 'safe'],
   ];
}
```

Comment: thank you..now its working..i added safe to name and value..Can we add rules like if the name is email and then validate curresponding  value field

Comment: yes.. if you add rules you don't need safe specification for the fields in rules. and you can add a name with validation rule email,  see validation guide on yii2 http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html